# Issue controlling the scroll of a view in an AppBarLayout if there is a pinned item before

Tags: java, android, android-appcompat, androiddesignsupport

I started testing the design support library with the [Chris Banes' Cheesesquare](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) example.

The most similar layout to my target is the main activity one: [LINK](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/include_list_viewpager.xml). But I tried to change the behavior and the things got broken.

What I'm trying to do is (see images below) scroll the red view only when the user scrolls

[image]
[image]

I tried with this layout but it doesn't scroll the red view. AS soon as I remove the `scroll|enterAlways` flags from the toolbar everything seems to stop working

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="#f00"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"></FrameLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```